# To which SCOP Class corresponds the following secondary structure?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, classification

I need to classify this protein into one of the SCOP class (all $\alpha$, all $\beta$, $\alpha +\beta$, $\alpha/\beta$, or small protein).
[image: Protein to classify] 
I'm having difficulties understanding the difference between $\alpha +\beta$ and $\alpha/\beta$. I would have said, that it belongs to the group $\alpha/\beta$, due to the fact that presents an alternated combination of $\alpha$-helices and $\beta$-sheets, where the $\beta$-sheets are mainly parallel, but I do not know if I'm understanding the concept right.

Has anyone a tip to identify the differences quicker?